# Issue getting started with MS Project Spark

Tags: technical-issues, windows-8, project-spark

I am trying Project Spark for the first time. After launching the game, I get the introduction video, prompt to accept few T&C and then a prompt to login to my Live account. Once all that is completed, I got this loading screen (below), in which the game is stuck forever. I tried leaving it to load for hours & also restarting (both game as well as PC), with nothing changed.

[image: Project Spark Loading Screen]

**Update:**
Tried <kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>tab</kbd>, and couldn't see any error message/popups.

Also, the process running for Project Spark seems to be sitting idle in Task Manager. It is consuming only 400 MB RAM and 0% processor utilization. See below a screenshot of the Task Manager entry for it,

[image]

Has anyone else faced the same issue and resolved it before?

**Update 2:**
The issue is resolved after installing a recent Windows update! Not sure if it really is linked to it though, but appears to be so.

Comment: have you tried running in windowed mode? You may be getting a popup asking for permission that is being blocked by the fullscreen

Comment: Alt-Tab would also potentially show the popup.

Comment: I tried <kbd>alt</kbd>+<kbd>tab</kbd> and I don't see any error message/popups. @Rapitor: is there a way to run Apps in windowed mode, other than using a 3rd part application?

Comment: If you did resolve this (even if it's not clear why the Windows update helped), it would be helpful to post it as an answer, for future visitors to find it easier.

Comment: @Anko done, I have posted my recent update as an answer too!

Answer (score 2):

The solution that worked for me is, to download the updates for Windows, install all pending updates, perform a restart and then launch Project Spark. This actually fixed my problem - the profile is now connected to PS server and the game menu is displayed.

PS: I am not exactly sure, if any of those windows updates were even relevant to PS.